# Differentiability in an interval

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose $f(x)=\begin{cases}
x^2\sin\dfrac{1}{x},& x\ne0\\
0,& x=0
\end{cases}$

It is continuous at $x=0$, it is differentiable at $x=0$, $f'(0)=0$

Can we say $f(x)$ is differentiable at $\forall$ $x$?

**If yes, then we can differentiate it**.

$f'(x)=2x\sin\dfrac{1}{x}-\cos\dfrac{1}{x}$

$f'(0)$ is undefined here. It means our assumption was wrong, so function is not differentiable at $\forall x$

So now it raises a question can we differentiate a function only if it is differentiable at $x$ or if it is differentiable in some finite interval like $(2,5)$?

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)$ is differentiable everywhere.

$$f'(x)=2x\sin\dfrac{1}{x}-\cos\dfrac{1}{x}$$ is valid for all $x\not =0$ and if $x=0$ then you have $f'(x)=0$

The derivative does not have to expressed with the same formula everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression for the derivative is correct for $x\neq 0$.

To check differentiability at $x=0$, use the definition of the derivative, i.e. see if the limit
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}$$
exists.

Comment: see what is asked in the question.

Comment: You ask if $f(x)$ is everywhere differentiable. The answer is you must see if this limit exists to verify differentiability at zero. As for the final question, I do not understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

The expression $x^{2}\cdot \sin (1/x)$ is defined as *f(x)* for $x\neq 0$. It is said so in the question.

The function has been split to overcome the removable discontinuity that arises because of an undefined value at 0.

So when you take the derivative of the function at 0, you can only take the derivative of what *f(x)* is defined as, at 0.

Comment: Can anyone please help me with the LaTeX?

Comment: put dollar sign '$' before and after your math expression.

Answer (score -1):

It is differentiable but not $C^1$. $f'(0)$ is defined, what are undefined are the limits $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} f'(x), \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^-} f'(x)$.